# Why is the key not recognized in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing code that receives information through TCP/IP communication in Unity and updates the position of each object based on this. Here, we created a temporary project that summons objects based on keystrokes because we need additional work depending on the key. However, when this program actually operates, keystrokes are not properly recognized. It recognizes it well when it first starts, but after about 10 seconds after the program starts, it doesn't detect keystrokes from then on. It's clear that Update isn't called, seeing as the object's position is updated based on the incoming information. Is it because the Update function is called intermittently for some reason, and the key input is not received properly? Or is it some other reason? What should be the solution?
Below is the C# script used.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class TagObjectCreator2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string connectionIP = "127.0.0.1";
    public int connectionPort = 25001;
    IPAddress localAdd;
    TcpListener listener;
    TcpClient client;
    bool running;

    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public GameObject cylinderPrefab;
    public GameObject elsePrefab;

    public GameObject tempPrefab;

    Dictionary<string, GameObject> gameObjects = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

    Thread receiveThread;

    private Queue<string> dataQueue = new Queue<string>();

    private void Start()
    {
        receiveThread = new Thread(ReceiveDataThread);
        receiveThread.Start();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Key가 눌렸습니다.");
            Instantiate(tempPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        // Check if there's any data in the queue
        string dataReceived = null;
        lock (dataQueue)
        {
            if (dataQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                dataReceived = dataQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }

        if (dataReceived != null)
        {
            ProcessReceivedData(dataReceived);
        }
    }

    // Thread for TCP/IP Communication
    private void ReceiveDataThread()
    {
        localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(connectionIP);
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, connectionPort);
        listener.Start();
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        running = true;
        while (running)
        {
            if (client.Available > 0)
            {
                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataReceived = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                Debug.Log("Received data: " + dataReceived); // 추가된 부분

                lock (dataQueue)
                {
                    dataQueue.Enqueue(dataReceived);
                }
            }
        }

        listener.Stop();
    }

    private void ProcessReceivedData(string dataReceived)
    {
        List<DataObject> dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataObject>>(dataReceived);

        HashSet<string> receivedNames = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (DataObject dataObject in dataObjects)
        {
            receivedNames.Add(dataObject.Name);

            Vector3 receivedPos = new Vector3(dataObject.Position.x, dataObject.Position.y, dataObject.Position.z);

            if (gameObjects.ContainsKey(dataObject.Name))
            {
                gameObjects[dataObject.Name].transform.position = receivedPos;
            }
            else
            {
                GameObject newObj;
                if (dataObject.ObjectType == "Table")
                {
                    newObj = Instantiate(cubePrefab, receivedPos, Quaternion.identity);
                }
                else if (dataObject.ObjectType == "robotic vacuum")
                {
                    newObj = Instantiate(cylinderPrefab, receivedPos, Quaternion.identity);
                }
                else
                {
                    newObj = Instantiate(elsePrefab, receivedPos, Quaternion.identity);
                }
                Debug.Log(dataObject.Name + "이/가 추가되었습니다.");
                gameObjects.Add(dataObject.Name, newObj);
            }
        }

        List<string> namesToRemove = new List<string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, GameObject> pair in gameObjects)
        {
            if (!receivedNames.Contains(pair.Key))
            {
                Debug.Log(pair.Key + "이/가 삭제되었습니다.");
                Destroy(pair.Value);
                namesToRemove.Add(pair.Key);
            }
        }

        foreach (string name in namesToRemove)
        {
            gameObjects.Remove(name);
        }

        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OK");
        nwStream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        running = false;
        if (receiveThread != null && receiveThread.IsAlive)
        {
            receiveThread.Abort();
        }
    }

    public class DataObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ObjectType { get; set; }
        public PositionData Position { get; set; }
    }

    public class PositionData
    {
        public float x { get; set; }
        public float y { get; set; }
        public float z { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general in an asynchronous context you would rather use a thread-safe `ConcurrentQueue` otherwise the behavior might be quite unpredictable .. how do you know it doesn't detect the key presses? you spawn all objects on the same place and then never move them .. maybe you just don't see a change?

Comment: Also `It's clear that Update isn't called, seeing as the object's position is updated based on the incoming information.` .. you mean it **is** called, right? Also you only process one received message per `Update` call what if they pile up? And just a very minor: You could save a bit performance and garbage by caching the bytes for `Ok` and always send the same ones ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thank you! 
There was a little problem with the code, so I fixed it, and now it works. It was also applied to saving by making the additional messages to be sent the same.